# How to create element by element comparison matrix in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose there is a pandas series (e.g. the following)

```
1 A
2 C
3 A
4 B
5 C
```

There is also a list of elements, e.g. [A,B,C,D]. The goal is to get a dataframe with columns of this list and the same rows, as in series, and each cell is a Boolean value which indicates if the value in series is equal to value of column. In my example it would be the following:

```
    A     B     C     D
1 True  False False False
2 False False True  False
3 True  False False False
4 False True  False False
5 False False True  False
```

Of course this can be achieved with a simple for loop (smth like this:)

```
for i in the_list:
   df[i] = the_series == i
```

But this is painfully slow, especially when the list is large. So what I am asking is if there is a faster "pandas-style" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `get_dummies`

```
s = s.str.get_dummies().astype(bool)
```

Comment: or `pd.get_dummies(s,dtype=bool)` directly :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, although it works for the example in provided, it doesn't fully solve the problem I have because i need to maintain particular order and also include values in columns that doesn't come up in series

Comment: @kandi s = s.str.get_dummies().astype(bool).reindex(columns=yourorder)

Comment: check my answer that maintains order. you can use `.reindex` too

Answer (score 1):

Try this method -

`pd.get_dummies` gets you one hot encoded version of the series and as type changes 1 to `True` and 0 to `False`.

```
s = pd.Series(['A','B','C','B','D','A','C'])
cols = ['A','B','C','D'] #put the order of your columns here

pd.get_dummies(s).astype(bool)[cols]
```

```
       A      B      C      D
0   True  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  False
3  False   True  False  False
4  False  False  False   True
5   True  False  False  False
6  False  False   True  False
```